# Pie Chart: Plot and Legend Mismatch

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a pie chart using R and ggplot2, more or less according to [example #128 of the R Graph Gallery](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/128-ring-or-donut-plot/).

```
piePlot <- function(count, categories) {
  dat <- data.frame(count = count, category = categories)
  dat$fraction <- dat$count / sum(dat$count)
  dat$ymax <- cumsum(dat$fraction)
  dat$ymin <- c(0, head(dat$ymax, n = -1))
  dat$label <- paste(dat$category, dat$count)
  plot <-
    ggplot(dat, aes(
      fill = category,
      ymax = ymax,
      ymin = ymin,
      xmin = 0,
      xmax = 1
    )) +
    geom_rect() +
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    scale_fill_brewer(labels = dat$label, guide = "legend")
  plot
}

piePlot(count = c(20, 10, 30),
        categories = c("one", "two", "three"))
```

Here's the output:

[image: Output]

The colors of the legend mismatch. The biggest are is supposed to be the darkest (three 30) according to the legend, which is obviously not the case. Here's a printout of my data frame right before the plot:

```
  count category  fraction      ymax      ymin    label
1    20      one 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000   one 20
2    10      two 0.1666667 0.5000000 0.3333333   two 10
3    30    three 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.5000000 three 30
```

This is exactly the legend's order, but ggplot seems to reorder the fields somehow when doing the plot. I just cannot understand why.

I'm using R version 3.4.2 and ggplot2 version 2.2.1.

Does anybody know how and why this reordering is taking place, and how I could suppress it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mismatch occurs because `ggplot()` orders the legend alphabetically in the first place, i.e. the legend entries would read "one 20, three 30, two 10" from top to bottom if you would not have called `scale_fill_brewer` But you overwrite the legend's entries to be "one 20, two 30, three 10". One way around this is to define the `dat$label` as a factor with levels c("one 20", "two 10", "three 30") so the legend is ordered by the factor levels.

To cut a long story short, the code below should solve your problem:

```
piePlot <- function(count, categories) {
dat <- data.frame(count = count, category = categories)
dat$fraction <- dat$count / sum(dat$count)
dat$ymax <- cumsum(dat$fraction)
dat$ymin <- c(0, head(dat$ymax, n = -1))
dat$label <- factor(paste(dat$category, dat$count), levels = paste(dat$category, dat$count))
plot <-
ggplot(dat, aes(
  fill = label, # fill by label not category
  ymax = ymax,
  ymin = ymin,
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 1
)) +
geom_rect() +
coord_polar(theta = "y") +
scale_fill_brewer(guide = "legend") # no need for labels anymore
plot
}

library(ggplot2)
piePlot(count = c(20, 10, 30),
    categories = c("one", "two", "three"))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I was already a bit suspicious because everybody was using factors for those kinds of plots. Now I know why :-)